# Checking for error or vbNullString type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data and I want to loop through and deal with any cells containing **either nothing, or an error**.

The code I tried is below and it gives me a `Type mismatch` because I cannot compare `Error 2042` with `vbNullString`.

```
' // doesn't work when value is #NA
For row = 1 To 10
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 1) = vbNullString Or IsError(Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)) Then
        'do something
    End If
Next row
```

Firstly I tried switching the logicals around in the `Or` to see if it skips to `do something` as soon as it finds a `True` but it evaluates both statements first.

I have thought of a number of other ways around this but none of them seem like the best way to go about it. I'm sure there must be a simple, clean way to do this?

```
' Option 1
For row = 1 To 10
    If IsError(Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)) Then
        'do something
    ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(row, 1) = vbNullString Then
        'do the same stuff
    End If
Next row



'Option 2
For row = 1 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 1) = vbNullString Then
        On Error GoTo 0 
        'do something
    End If  
Next row



'Option 3
Dim testValue As Variant
If IsError(Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)) Then
    testValue = vbNullString
Else
    testValue = Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)
End If

For row = 1 To 10
    If testValue = vbNullString Then
        'do something
    End If
Next row
```

Perhaps option 2 is the best, but it doesn't really mean much for anyone reading my code (also, I never want to lose a genuine error).

For purposes of testing you can assume my data looks something like this (`A1:A10`)

```
1
2

4
#N/A
6
#N/A

9
10
```

Comment: instead of `vbNullString` try `If Len(Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)) =  0 Then` , Or the old `If Sheet1.Cells(row, 1) = "" Then`

Comment: I still get a type mismatch when evaluating on the error term

Comment: @ShaiRado - `Len({Error})` is also a type mismatch.

Comment: you're right my bad, if the cell has `#NA` you can if it equals `CVErr(xlErrNA)` , also you can check `CVErr(xlErrDiv0 )` , etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your own data validation function and call that:

```
Public Function IsEmptyOrError(test As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsError(test) Then Exit Function
    IsEmptyOrError = CStr(test) = vbNullString
End Function
```

Calling code:

```
For Row = 1 To 10
    If IsEmptyOrError(Sheet1.Cells(row, 1)) Then
        'do something
    End If
Next Row
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1 but you could try this instead. Btw don't use Row as a variable name as it's a VBA property. (And don't ask me why this works when If doesn't.)

```
Sub x()

Dim Row1 As Long

For Row1 = 1 To 10
    Select Case True
        Case IsError(Sheet1.Cells(Row1, 1)), Sheet1.Cells(Row1, 1) = vbNullString
        'do something
    End Select
Next Row1

End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like option 1 is the worst because you end up writing the same code twice. Also I don't tend to use `row` as a variable name for that reason but is there actually any other reason not to? it certainly more readable than `row1`. Interesting answer, thank you.

Comment: It's a `Range`'s property, nothing VBA-specific. And there's absolutely nothing wrong with declaring a local variable `row`, other than it annoyingly will turn `MyRange.Row` into `MyRange.row` because the language is case-insensitive. You could even have a local variable named `rows`, and it would "hide" the global-scoped `Rows` property, which implicitly refers to the `ActiveSheet` and shouldn't be used unqualified anyway.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - fair enough. I still think it's preferable not to use when there are so many other variable names to pick from!

Comment: Sure, ...except `row` tends to be a very meaningful name to describe... a *row*. I usually go with `currentRow` though, so yeah. Damn Excel stole all the good names!

Answer (score 1):

edit to add a 2nd approach

- `AutoFilter()`approach:

  ```
  With Sheet1 '<--| reference your sheet
      With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="#N/A" '<--| filter referenced range on its 1st (and only) column with "" or "#N/A" values 
          If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filterd cells other than header
              With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered cells skipping header
                  'do something with referenced range containing all wanted values
              End With
          End If
      End With
      .AutoFilterMode = False
  End With
  ```
- `SpecialCells()` approach:

  ```
  Dim myRng As Range
  With Sheet1
      Set myRng = GetErrorsAndBlanks(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
      If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
          'do something with 'myRng'
      End If
  End With
  ```

  where you'd use the following `GetErrorsAndBlanks`() function:

  ```
  Function GetErrorsAndBlanks(rng As Range) As Range
      With rng
          Set GetErrorsAndBlanks = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) '<--| initialize select range with a dummy cell, to be taken away before exiting
          On Error Resume Next
          Set GetErrorsAndBlanks = Union(GetErrorsAndBlanks, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors)) '<--| try and get "error" cells deriving from constants
          Set GetErrorsAndBlanks = Union(GetErrorsAndBlanks, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)) '<--| try and get "error" cells deriving from formulas
          Set GetErrorsAndBlanks = Union(GetErrorsAndBlanks, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)) '<--| try and get "blank" cells
          Set GetErrorsAndBlanks = Intersect(GetErrorsAndBlanks, .Cells) '<--| take "dummy" cell away
      End With
  End Function
  ```